# Is populate implicit and how many levels deep can it go?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have been tasked to modify an existing (large) node.js web using `mongoose`.

The schema has a `Question` which links to an array of `Answer` as follows:

```
var QuestionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   text: { type: String },
   ...
   answers: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer'}],
   ...
});

var AnswerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   text: { type: String },
   ....
   question: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: Question
   },
...
});     
var Question  = mongoose.model('Story', QuestionSchema);
var Answer = mongoose.model('Answer', AnswerSchema);
```

I couldn't locate any instance of the `populate` method being used in the code, but a query of a `Question` document always return with the array of full `answer` objects, not just the object id.  This is what is needed.

I now have to add an array of `reaction` objects to `answer`. I used the following:

```
var Answer = mongoose.model('Answer', AnswerSchema);
var ReactionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: { type: String },
    .... 
    answer: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: Answer,
       //required: true
    },
    ...
});
```

I then added the following to the `Answer` schema:

```
reactions: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Reaction'}]
//where var Reaction  = mongoose.model('Reaction', ReactionSchema);
```

I am able to save `reaction` objects, and when I inspected the database contents of `answer`, the `reaction` objects are the same in type and form to `answer` objects in `question`.

However, when a `question` document is returned, each element of `answer.reaction` contains just the object id of `reaction` instead of the full `reaction` object. What have I omitted or how do I make the query to perform the join based on the `ref` type?

The mongodb version is 3.2.9, and mongoose is 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you query a Question? This is how you can resolve nested references:

```
Question.findById(id).populate({
  path: 'answer',
  model: 'Answer',
  populate: {
    path: 'reaction',
    model: 'Reaction'
  }
}).exec(function(err, data){});
```

Here is the link to the mongoose docs: [Mongoose Docs Deep Populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer gave me the clue to solving the problem. My version of mongo does not have the populate method at all. I spent more time digging into the existing code and finally found the code that manually retrieved the `answer` objects from the object ids stored in `question.answers` and then added them to the question document that was returned.